# XGBoost model: train on GPU, run on CPU without GPU RAM allocation

Tags: python, gpu, cpu, xgboost, predict

How can I train an XGBoost model on a GPU but run predictions on CPU **without allocating *any* GPU RAM**?

My situation: I create an XGBoot model (`tree_method='gpu_hist'`) in Python with `predictor='cpu_predictor'`, then I train it on GPU, then I save (pickle) it to disk, then I read the model from disk, then I use it for predictions.

My problem: once the model starts doing predictions, even though I run it on CPU, it still allocates some small amount of GPU RAM (around ~289MB). This is a problem for the following reasons:

- I run multiple copies of the model to parallelize predictions and if I run too many, the prediction processes crash.
- I can not use GPU for training other models, if I run predictions on the same machine at the same time.

So, how can one tell XGBoost to not allocate *any* GPU RAM and use CPU and regular RAM only for predictions?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: stumbling upon this same issue. did you end up solving it?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the model being saved as pickle

When I loaded and re-saved the model in either JSON or BIN formats, the problem was gone.